# How to Install Linux without CD/USB

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, grub, iso, debian-installer

I have a machine with no CD/DVD drive. I do not own a USB. This device has only 32gigs of memory.  I have a Kali iso that I want to install on it.  The notebook currently runs on Debian. Any ideas on how this can be done?  Would I be able to use grub2's isoboot?

Comment: Welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get more information on how to best post to this site. Sounds like you are already aware of a solution. What have you tried and what is not working? You already have a working Debian install, why is it necessary to switch over to Kali? Many of the tools Kali comes with even work on Windows computers.

Answer (score 1):

There are methods not specifically documented for Kali which work for [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux) and [Debian](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en). However, since you have Debian, and [Debian is the foundation of Kali](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/what-is-kali-linux), you may add [the packages](https://tools.kali.org/) to your Debian install to let it do what Kali does, including downloading, building, and installing the [Kali kernel](https://docs.kali.org/development/recompiling-the-kali-linux-kernel).